# Internationalization of an Eclipse RCP 3.8 app: JFace dialog values not loaded

Tags: internationalization, eclipse-rcp

I want to translate an Eclipse RCP application based on Juno 3.8. For the Eclipse platform I downloaded the respective Babel language pack for German: [BabelLanguagePack-eclipse-de_4.2.0.v20121120043402.zip](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.10.1/juno/juno.php).

Everything seems to work fine except for the buttons in the JFace dialogs: Cancel, Next etc. are not translated. The respective fragment (org.eclipse.jface.nl_de_4.2.0.v20121120043402.jar) which contains the translations is loaded correctly (I can see it in the plugin details) but the German values are not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle you have specified is for the version 4.2 (but you are using 3.8). This may be the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but I cannot find packages for 3.8, seems these packs are only available for 4.2

Comment: I'm using [Babel P2 Repository](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.10.0/indigo) from Eclipse 3.8 and do get the correct language packs.

Comment: @mav-ver-ick: thanks, but your link goes to the Indigo update site (3.7), but this maybe better works with 3.8 than the 4.2 packages, I will try that (if I go to the Juno update site I only see the 4.2 packages).

Comment: Ah! AFAIK the 3.8 is more like a bugfix release :). They are concentrating on the 4.x release train...